# Specifying goal in Maven clean package

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am building a WebAPI.war file using Maven. The problem I am facing is that the target war file is not getting generated. On the Windows console after I ran this what I found were goals missing in pom.xml.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.5:execute (add-git-branch-info) on project WebAPI: Execution add-git-branch-info of goal org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.5:execute failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.5:execute: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null

This is the part of the pom.xml the error is hinting at.

Any help is appreciated!

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.5</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>add-git-branch-info</id>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>execute</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <source>
          if (project.properties.getProperty("git.branch") == null) project.properties.setProperty("git.branch", "*");
          if (project.properties.getProperty("git.commit.id.abbrev") == null) project.properties.setProperty("git.commit.id.abbrev", "*");
        </source>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Remove gmaven-plugin... it's really old...better use [git-commit-id-maven-plugin](https://github.com/git-commit-id/git-commit-id-maven-plugin)...

Comment: BTW: The plugin is 10 years old...use more recent tools

Comment: Use the referenced plugin it's easier... why should a plugin work with webapi for tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

GMaven plugin is missing `providerSelection` that specifies which groovy version to use :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-git-branch-info</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <providerSelection>2.0</providerSelection>
                <source>
                    if (project.properties.getProperty("git.branch") == null) project.properties.setProperty("git.branch", "*");
                    if (project.properties.getProperty("git.commit.id.abbrev") == null) project.properties.setProperty("git.commit.id.abbrev", "*");
                </source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you Issam, but this still gives the same error report as previous.

Comment: @Vani did you put <providerSelection>2.0</providerSelection> in configuration tag inside execution tag?

Comment: Yes i put it in configuration tag